# Project Management Tool

Tags: project-management, projects-and-solutions, bug-tracking

Everybody,

I would like to ask you what is the most useful software to handle the lifetime of a project.
I will explain my need.

I'm working with some people in another town, and I will be the project manager of the project. I will receive the specifications from the client and send it to my developers (after slice it).
What I need is a tool where to put all the specifications (by small slice for instance) and each  developer must write down the state of the development for each slice. 
Using this I should be able to se which part is finished, which part is in progress.
I'm thinking to have also a bug handling process. I will test what is finished and create some sort of ticket for each bug.
The developers will receive a notification and for each bug fixed, they should be able to change some flag.

So, with something like that I should be able to monitor the development (what is finished, what is in progress, what bugs are stil open, etc).

I know MS Project Manager (but is not a web solution), some bug tracking solution, but nothing with all I want together.

So, does anyone knows some tool able to do that ?

I'm thinking at some web solution.

Thank you very much for any suggestion.

Best regards,
itsme.

Comment: As I said, I know some tool but nothing with all I need together.

Comment: still. if people think your qw is valid they will upvote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think ASANA (http://asana.com/) can fulfill your requirements, but it is slightly expensive. For an opensource solution take a look at http://www.project.net/. You can install it on a web server and use it for free. It can also easily be customized by programming.

best regards

Comment: Asana looks awesome. It's exactly what I need. I will search something like that, maybe I will find something similar open source. Thanks.

Comment: You can also take a look in http://www.batbugger.io